# Angular Simple Directive ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-ng-if

I do not know how to write my condition in angular and I can not find an equate example.

How i can listen to my material selection ?

How I  write a ngIf condition ?

{{referentielToDisplay.speSS}} have a equal value of one of my toppingList, i want to write :

if ReferentielToDisplay. speSS is equal to an item selected in the material selection so:  display this card

```
*ngIf="referentielToDisplay.speSS === topping"
```

Component.html

```
<mat-form-field style="width:100%" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Sélectionner une spécialité</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple="true" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping" >{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div  *ngFor="let referentielToDisplay  of referentielsToDisplay | async" >
<mat-card *ngIf="referentielToDisplay.speSS === topping">
{{referentielToDisplay.nomSS}}
</mat-card>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
toppings = new FormControl( );
toppingList: string[] = ['Multi-spécialité','Hématologie', 'Neurologie', 'Urologie', 'Digestif', 'Endocrinologie',  'Pneumologie', 'ORL','Dermatologie', 'Sein-Gynecologie'];
```

Comment: Unclear. what is "my data"? What is "my table"? Where is `topping`defined? Are you asking how to test if toppingList contains referentielToDisplay.speSS? Look at the documentation of array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Aren't "topping" in <mat-select> and <div> where you are comparing out of scope? Check visibility of "topping"

Comment: How i can listen topping of my mat selct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*ngIf="toppings.value.includes(referentielToDisplay.speSS)"
```

It's not totaly the solution but it is the way !!

Comment: it's directly `toppings.value && toppings.value === referentielToDisplay.speSS`

Comment: Thank you Julien !!

Comment: Pas de soucis ! ;)

Comment: @JulienMetral Tu es développeur sur angular ? pourrion nous discuter sur le chat ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf) condition :

```
<mat-card *ngIf="toppingList.indexOf(referentielToDisplay.speSS) > -1">
  {{referentielToDisplay.nomSS}}
</mat-card>
```

Or

```
<mat-card *ngIf="toppingList.includes(referentielToDisplay.speSS)">
  {{referentielToDisplay.nomSS}}
</mat-card>
```

Ìt checks if the list contains your value `referentielToDisplay.speSS`

Comment: Thanks i reformulated my question beacause i want *ngIf="{{referentielToDisplay.nomSS}}.indexOf(topping) > -1" but if doesn't work

Comment: Remove those double curly braces. Note that there is an includes method in array: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/includes

Comment: it s the same. I think my probleme is the listenning of mat selection

Comment: Your problem is that your question is extremely unclear, and you're not answering questions, nor making it clearer. So it's basically impossible to help you.

Comment: Oops sorry that was `toppingList.indexOf(referentielToDisplay.speSS)`

Comment: `toppingList.indexOf(referentielToDisplay.speSS) > 1` checks if toppingList contains `referentielToDisplay.speSS` do you mind ?

Comment: Very strange. With that i have juste only one card displaying and the selected values on form do nothing

Comment: Ah ok, you want to check if `referentielToDisplay.speSS` is equal to the current value of your form control ?